# Riley Riddle: My infix describes its own letters

Tags: riddle, word

My prefix makes rulers,

My suffix is ruled,

My infix describes its own letters,

My whole keeps food cooled.

Edit: here are some hints:

> While the answer to this riddle does indeed help to keep food cool, that may not be the first thing you think about when hearing the word.

> What with all the talk about rulers and ruling, this is in many ways a riddle about power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

> Electricity

My prefix makes rulers,

> In a representative democracy, you **elect** a ruler.

My suffix is ruled,

> A **city** is a place governed by a ruler.

My infix describes its own letters,

> **tri** is a three-letter word for three. Hence, it describes it own letters. This one was clever!

My whole keeps food cooled.

> **Electricity** is used by your refrigerator and freezer to store your foods at a low temperature, among many other things.

Good riddle!

Answer (score 0):

> Supermarket

> Being Super is essential for a ruler as one needs to be better than the norm.

> Markets are governed by a manager.

> Mark, the letters I guess are marks on a piece of paper when you write them down.

> Supermarkets keeps food chilled.

Comment: A very good try, but not the answer I had in mind. (In particular, none of the fixes are substrings of any other fixes, though they may have overlap.) I'll add a hint or two to make things less ambiguous.